# Preventing CKEDITOR from modifying HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm trying to force CKE to stop modifying my HTML wildly, and trying to introduce our own rules.

For example, CKE will remove empty *span* and *i* tags, we can prevent it from doing it with

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = false
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = false
```

So far so good. Then we tried to make *A* tags to be able to support block level elements (HTML5), which we were able to do by manipulating the DTD as well.

But now it seems the DTD object is not enough for what we are trying to do.
For example, it's removing empty *A* tags, and I can't prevent it from doing it,

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.a = false
```

will not do the trick. It's doing the same thing with empty *BR* tags located at the end of the content.

I know CKE is using a filter, parser, processor or something that I need to hook onto and modify/alter it in order to stop it from doing those changes. Could you please give me any advise on how to achieve this ?

Cordially, Agustin.

## UPDATE

I'm also looking forward in adding an extra supported children to *SELECT* tag. Select supports optgroup and option as children, I'm trying to add support for a custom_tag (inline), but I can't succeed in making it happen.

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.select.custom_tag = 1
```

Is not doing it. The custom tag is also declared on dtd.$inline
I guess there is some sort of external processing cleaning it up, and I can't control this from the DTD object. Any pointer on this regard ?

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/CKEditor-disable-auto-editing-HTML-code

Answer (score 2):

To disable filtering HTML (source) in CKEditor write in your `config.js` file this lines:

`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.allowedContent = true;
};`

[Source code here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/6f4c29002f4d6ecfa39308b641ae37c56bba1348/core/filter.js#L123).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately empty links are a special case and to stop removing them you will need to modify the source:

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/6f4c29002f4d6ecfa39308b641ae37c56bba1348/core/htmlparser/fragment.js#L59-L66

```
function isRemoveEmpty( node ) {
    // Keep marked element event if it is empty.
    if ( node.attributes[ 'data-cke-survive' ] )
        return false;

    // Empty link is to be removed when empty but not anchor. (#7894)
    return node.name == 'a' && node.attributes.href || CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty[ node.name    ];
}
```

BTW. CKEditor removes empty inline elements, because they are not editable (and some things may start working incorrectly). To ensure correct editability of these elements you can write [widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro) for them.

Comment: What about BR at the end of the contents, do you see that happening on the source as well ?  Maybe BR is not as important as the tweak I need to make on the SELECT element.

Comment: BRs at the end of blocks are so called "bogus BRs" and, as the name indicate, they are bogus - they do not affect the rendering. However, they must be used by editors to fill empty blocks, because otherwise such blocks will be invisible (because of height = 0). That's a very long story, but BRs will be always removed from the end of non-empty blocks and that cannot changed.

Comment: Could you check if there is a way to add a custom tag into a SELECT tag (check my last question update) ? You seem to be the only one who could answer this. Thanks !

Comment: CKEditor has its parser, which most likely in this case can be tuned by modifying `CKEDITOR.dtd`, but it also uses native DOM. And the browsers may not accept your custom tags in a various ways. BTW. consider using `config.protectedSource`.